# Anyone got a xml parser with expandablelistview

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to implement an xml parser and the parsed result into an expandablelistview. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you planning to write an XML parser just to print result in an expandablelistview? Why not use an XML parser that already exist to do the job?
What is expandablelistview anyway?

Comment: Ordinary List view cannot show section headings, i want a tableview structure just like that in iphone

Comment: I did not notice android tag before. I have not worked on Android, but I guess you already are aware about class mentioned at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html if you are looking for information on how to you parse an XML you can use XML parsers like DOM parser. Although Android SDK already provides API to parse XML you can take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.html You can find a lot of examples on how to parse XML for example http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html